# adding ellipsis to last usable line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some code that looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.news-title').each(function() {
            var divh = jQuery(this).height();
            var aText = jQuery(this).children();
            var a = aText.outerHeight();
            if(a > divh) {
                jQuery(aText).text(function (index, text) {
                    return text.replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

It seems to half do what i would like, but it is missing an important part. I think that my replace text function is off. Instead of replacing the last word from the last usable line, it just replaces the last line. Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: As martynas says css would be better option, btw, I see above code working. are you dealing with utf?

Comment: I am not quite sure i know what you mean by that. Upon further investigation i am seeing that it is only working for some of my areas that are targeted rather than others. I dont know if that helps at all. Also, I would like to not use css because i feel that this is cleaner and i already invested a lot of time into this. Any ideas what is going on here? My outside div area is 200x40 pixels

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make use of text-overflow ellipsis property:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

This should be a comment but i don't have enough rep :/

Answer (score 0):

try with below regex, guessing text might be ending with a space

```
/\W*\s(\S)+\s*$/
```